# Order of Execution during Sync Quote

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, quote, sync

I am trying to find what happens when Sync Quote is clicked on the Quote. What is the order of execution (Opportunity updated prior to OpportunityLineItem or vice-versa)? The execution flow is important because one of our logic works fine if sync is on and Quote is edited but doesn't work when Sync Quote is turned on after quote is edited.

I tried going through the debug logs and didn't find any OpportunityLineItem triggers fired.

Comment: please add more details on what you are trying to do? what events are firing (as per your understanding)? What are you exactly looking for ? Once we have more details, we (community) will be able to help better :)

Comment: this may be helpful: `When you modify an opportunity product on an opportunity, or when an opportunity product schedule changes an opportunity product, even if the opportunity product changes the opportunity, the before and after triggers and the validation rules don't fire for the opportunity. However, roll-up summary fields do get updated, and workflow rules associated with the opportunity do run`

Comment: That is helpful. However, my starting point is Quote Sync and I am more interested in the sequence from their - Do Opportunities get updated first or Line Items and do these updates results in firing triggers for the respective objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with an example that I have created a Quote and Quote comes with QuoteLineItem as same as OpportunityLineItem. I Press the (StartSync) button on Quote and checked the debug I found that trigger sequence below :

- Before/ After Update On Opportunity
- Before/ After Update On Quote

Also tried with Created a Quote and changed the Quantity of QuoteLineItem then Press the (StartSync) Button, Sequence was :

- Before/ After Update On Opportunity
- Before/ After Update On Quote
- Before/ After Update OpportunityLineItem
- Before/ After Update on Opportunity